# SQL count records with 0 Value

Tags: sql

I'm using a SQL query for an app, but I cant get it to count values with 0 results.

The code is shown below:

```
select CarrierPosition, COUNT(*) as FailCount
from tbl_0000000024,
     tbl_0000000025
where asictestdate >= DATEADD(hour,-6, getdate())
  and FK_AS0000000032 = fk_as0000000056
  and fk_as0000000046 = '135'
  and FailReason = '151'
  and tbl_0000000025.Status = ' Current'
group by CarrierPosition
Order by CarrierPosition
```

It should show up a fail count for 8 positions, but leaves out positions 1 and 4 as they have a FailCount of 0. How do I get it to show the other 2 rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do a `LEFT JOIN`, modern explicit syntax, to get those rows too.

```
select CarrierPosition, COUNT(*) as FailCount
from tbl_0000000024
LEFT JOIN tbl_0000000025 ON FK_AS0000000032 = fk_as0000000056
where asictestdate >= DATEADD(hour,-6, getdate())
  and fk_as0000000046 = '135'
  and FailReason = '151'
  and tbl_0000000025.Status = ' Current'
group by CarrierPosition
Order by CarrierPosition
```

(Perhaps it should be the other way, the column and table names don't describe very well. Switch LEFT to RIGHT and see what happens if the above query doesn't work as expected.)

Comment: For extra explanations see this venn diagrams of sql joins : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg

Comment: You should add some kind of explanation to your answer... you know... for SQL newbies :)

Comment: Thanks for your help.

FK_AS0000000056 is on tbl_25 and FK_AS0000000032 is on tbl_24 - both are the part ID.

I'd been playing about with Joins earlier but I think I had syntax wrong. This one will execute but gives the same responses, even with left and right swapped.

Comment: Reposting in case you missed my edit (I'm new to this) 
Thanks for your help. FK_AS0000000056 is on tbl_25 and FK_AS0000000032 is on tbl_24 - both are the part ID. I'd been playing about with Joins earlier but I think I had syntax wrong. This one will execute but gives the same responses, even with left and right swapped